# CGContextSetStrokeColor is not working inside drawLayer:inContext:

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, quartz-core

I am trying to draw a line inside CALayer inside a UIView. I have set the delegate of CALayer and implemented the `drawLayer:inContext:` method. following is the method:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)theContext
{
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(theContext, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
  CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
  CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath,NULL,15.0f,15.f);
  CGPathAddCurveToPoint(thePath,
                        NULL,
                        15.f,250.0f,
                        295.0f,250.0f,
                        295.0f,15.0f);
  CGContextBeginPath(theContext);
  CGContextAddPath(theContext, thePath);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(theContext, 5);

  CGContextDrawPath(theContext, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

this works fine and I am able to see a line with blue color. But when I try to change the `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` with `CGContextSetStrokeColor` like below. The line disappears and I am not able to see anything, why is this happening?

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)theContext
{
  CGContextSetStrokeColor(theContext, CGColorGetComponents([UIColor blueColor].CGColor));
  CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
  CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath,NULL,15.0f,15.f);
  CGPathAddCurveToPoint(thePath,
                        NULL,
                        15.f,250.0f,
                        295.0f,250.0f,
                        295.0f,15.0f);
  CGContextBeginPath(theContext);
  CGContextAddPath(theContext, thePath);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(theContext, 5);

  CGContextDrawPath(theContext, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

please let me know what the problem is with the second approach.

Comment: How do you know that `[UIColor blueColor].CGColor` has the same color space as the context?  Have you tried calling `CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(theContext, CGColorGetColorSpace([UIColor blueColor].CGColor))` first?  Or just use `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor`.  It is documented as the preferred API now and should take care of the color space for you.